# JAWS ( on windows ) not reading aria-label given on `<p>` tag

Tags: javascript, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I have given a specific aria-label for `<p>` tag in my web page.

```
<p aria-label="my custom text" className="inline">text</p>
```

The aria-label given on this is reading perfectly fine on Mac screen reader, but it is not happening on JAWS ( on windows ). Is there any **specific settings / extra tags** has to be added in order to read the same in JAWS ? Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 4):

The `aria-label` attribute may be ignored if the element you are setting it on doesn't have a specified role.  In your case, the `<p>` doesn't have any semantic meaning other than just text.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support

In particular, see the 8th bullet:

> Don't use `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby` on any other non-interactive content such as `p`, `legend`, `li`, or `ul`, because it is ignored.

As an aside, it's a little unusual to have paragraph text read differently than what is visually displayed.  So while you could use `aria-hidden` and the "visually-hidden" class, that will cause problems for low vision users who rely on augmenting their web experience by running a screen reader along with a magnifier.  They will be able to see some text on the screen but when they hear it, it won't match what they see.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `aria-label` you can use the visually hidden text by moving your text into a `<span>` with `aria-hidden="true"` attribute

E.g.

```
<p className="inline">
<span aria-hidden="true">text</span>
<span class="visually-hidden">my custom text</span>
</p>
```

And visually hidden class will have :

```
.visually-hidden{
position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}
```